# how to pass ngModel value from input to *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I have an input field, I wanna pass its data by using `[(ng model)]` to `*ngIf`

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputData">

<div *ngIf="cityName ==={{inputData}}; then mainpart else elsepart"></div>

<ng-template #mainpart>
  **Some Code Here**
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elsepart>
  **Some Code Here**
</ng-template>
```

I want when user enter some data in input field if data is matching with the `condition` then run `mainpart` else `elsepart` are run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<div *ngIf="cityName === inputData; then mainpart else elsepart"></div>
```

Also you don't need to use interpolation in *ngIf Condition

Comment: thanks Tony Bro for reply, but how we use input field data in *ngif on run time

Comment: ```cityName === inputData``` here it is. I using inputData to compare with cityName. Is that want you want ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cityName === inputData; then mainpart else elsepart"></ng-container>

<ng-template #mainpart><div>main content...</div></ng-template>
<ng-template #elsepart><div>else content...</div></ng-template>
```